# Getting Pixel Colour in Android from an imported image from gallery?

Tags: android

The problem of this code is,it only gets the colour value for all of the picture not for the place the user clicks/touches!
there must be a simple problem, i believe!
Here's the code, let's see what you can get! ;)

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MPActivity extends Activity {

private TextToSpeech mTts;
private ImageView targetImage;
private TextView textView;
private TextView textViewCol;
private TextView textViewVal;
private boolean hasTTSBeenInitialized = false;

private int imageWidth;
private int imageHeight;


     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     Button buttonLoadImage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loadimage);

 textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
 textViewCol = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewColor);
 targetImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.targetimage);
 textViewVal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewValue);

 targetImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.targetimage);

 buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

 @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
  startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
 }});
 mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, new OnInitListener() {      
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
        hasTTSBeenInitialized = true;
        }
      });

      mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
 }


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
 Uri targetUri = data.getData();
 Bitmap bitmap;
 try {
  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));
  //w2,h2
  imageWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
  imageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

  targetImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }


}

targetImage.setOnTouchListener(new ImageView.OnTouchListener(){     


public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    int x = ((int)event.getX() / v.getWidth() )  * imageWidth;
    int y = ((int)event.getY() / v.getHeight())  * imageHeight;

    textView.setText("Touch coordinates : "+String.valueOf(event.getX())+"x"+String.valueOf(event.getY()));
    ImageView imageView = ((ImageView)v);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    // Calculation -> x, y - image space 


    int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);

    textViewVal.setText("[" + Color.red(pixel) + "," + Color.green(pixel) + "," + Color.blue(pixel) + "]");

    if ((Color.red(pixel) > 200) && (Color.blue(pixel) < 10) && (Color.green(pixel) < 10)) {
        if(hasTTSBeenInitialized){
            mTts.speak("Color is RED", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
        textViewCol.setText("Color is Red."); 
    } 

    return true;    }     
});


}

}
```

Comment: Might be me that is too tired but I can not find any place in the code where you assign values to x and y.

Comment: Here, I updated my codes and I ALSO put RED as an example to be read by the program ... thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a problem with integer division. This expression probably yields zero:

```
(int)event.getX() / v.getWidth()
```

Since you've cast the value of `getX()` to an `int` and `getWidth()` returns an `int`, integer division happens, meaning the result gets truncated to the nearest lower integer. Instead, do the multiplication first before the division and leave the cast to last.

```
int x = (int) (event.getX() * imageWidth / v.getWidth());
int y = (int) (event.getY() * imageHeight / v.getHeight());
```

Comment: i appreciate it, it works very well ... but sorry, my reputation is too low i can't vote for ur answer!

Comment: Glad my answer was helpful. You should be able to accept it by clicking on the check mark next to it.